# How to not show all frequency in bar-chart and group them in same category in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

Sorry I am new in R!

I used table function to make a table using two different columns of a data frame like

```
C1 C2
A  2
B  1
A  2
C  1
A  1
C  3
D  2
```

C2 values are categories and I want to show frequency of each letter in C1 based on C2 values (here 1 and 2). I used function table as below to find the frequncy table.

```
t <- table(data$c1,data$c2)
```

Now I want to make a barchart using ggplot when x-axis  is C2 values (1,2,3,..) and y-axis is frequency of each letter of column C1. I also want to show only few letters (like 5) with high frequency in each bar not frequency of all letters and put the rest of them as one part named for example "other". For instance if I have for value 1, letters (A,B,D, F, G) have high frequency show them in bar and put all other letters frequency in one part labels as "Other" and next bar is for frequency of different letters for value 2 ,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a strech, but it gets the job done.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(C1 = sample(LETTERS, 200, replace = T), 
             C2 = sample(1:5, 200, replace = T))
df$C1 <- as.character(df$C1)


df1 <- df %>% group_by(C2, C1) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% arrange(desc(Count))
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(C2) %>% mutate(Index = 1:n())
df2$C1[df2$Index > 5] <- "Other"
df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(C2, C1) %>% summarise(updatedCount = sum(Count)) %>% 
    arrange(updatedCount) %>% 
    mutate(mid_y = ave(updatedCount, C2, FUN = function(val) cumsum(val) - (0.5 * val)))


ggplot(df3, aes(x = C2, y = updatedCount, fill = C1, label = C1)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    theme(legend.position="none") + geom_text(aes(y = mid_y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is very cool. how about if I had a table while rows are variable (1,2,3,..6) and columns are letters and I have frequency of each letter for every variable?

Comment: It would help if you could post a minimal example. But as far a I understand, all you need to do is use the `tidyr::gather` function to convert all the columns that are letters into rows - which is the preferred format for ggplot2

Comment: Great, please accept it as the answer if the code worked fine.